# Google drive and Firebase Google auth info ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-drive-api

I have an app with google auth configured with firebase. can I use the token generated by firebase to access google drive documents?

I want the user logged in inside the app with Gmail auth to be able to read a document on Google drive that is shared with him.

I can't find anything online about this case. 
I tried to open the document inside a webview but ask me to login to google drive

Answer (score 0):

you have to follow these steps in order to make Google Sign-In and access to drive work.

1. Go to your credentials
2. Choose OAuth consent screen
3. Fill all the required details
4. Choose OAuth client id
5. Fill all the required details and For SHA1 key use this ‘keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v’
6. Copy Client Id & use as reverse client id

**NOTE image Android**[image]

> Good Example
>   https://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/blog/implement-google-drive-api-ionic-2/